# Using preg_match_all from title

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I need to extract from post title strings like:

12ml
12 ml
123ml
123 ml
12.3ml
12.3 ml

Now im using:

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9]+\sml/i", $post->post_title, $percentage);             
if(isset($percentage[0][0]) && $percentage[0][0] != "" ){    
    $text = $percentage[0][0]." "; 
}
echo $text;
```

But dont know how to set it for point separated numbers.

Comment: you need only decimal number 12.3ml  12.3ml  is it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$str = "abc 12ml def 12 ml xyz 123ml tuv 123 ml jhsfg 12.3ml qjsdfkjfhg 12.3 ml";
if (preg_match_all("/\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*ml/i", $str, $percentage)) {
    print_r($percentage);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12ml
            [1] => 12 ml
            [2] => 123ml
            [3] => 123 ml
            [4] => 12.3ml
            [5] => 12.3 ml
        )

)
```

**Explanation:**

```
/           : regex delimiter
  \d+       : 1 or more digits
  (?:       : start non capture group
    \.      : a dot
    \d+     : 1 or more digits
  )?        : end group, optional
  \s*       : 0 or more spaces
  ml        : literally ml
/i          : regex delimiter, flag case insensitive
```